# Процедура сохранения или обновления данных с кавычками и точками

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Допустим, нехороший пользователь ввел в input, что с кавычками и точками:

```
ООО "Тазики и Ромашки". Мы работаем как рабы
```

Вот интересует, есть ли подводные камни, в плане таких фраз с кавычками и точками, и как этого избежать?

Comment: перед тем как вносить в базу нужно квотить все значения из $_REQUEST, $COOKIE, $_POST или $_GET и никаких камней, даже песка в почках не будет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перед заносом в базу делайте `mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['text'])`. 
При выводе -     `stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text_from_base,ENT_QUOTES))`

Comment: т.е. правильнее так писать:

    $field_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['$field_1']);
    $field_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['$field_2']);
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (field_1,field_2) VALUES ('$field_1','$field_2')");

    $field_1 = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($field_1,ENT_QUOTES));
    $field_2 = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($field_2,ENT_QUOTES));
    $query = "SELECT `field_1` FROM `table` WHERE `field_1`='$field_1' AND `field_2`='$field_2' LIMIT 0,1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $field_1 = $sql[1];
    $field_2 = $sql[2];

?

Comment: когда заносить - правильно. При выводе - stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($sql[1],ENT_QUOTES));

Comment: fetch_array не забывайте делать